# Приорететность перегруженных функций

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Всем привет. Имеется Visual C++ 2015 и код:

```
#define SHOW_ME printf("%s\n", __FUNCSIG__)
template <class T>
struct wrapper {
    int data = 10;
    wrapper() = default;                                      
    template <class U> wrapper(const wrapper<U>&) { SHOW_ME; }
};
```

Пытаюсь спровоцировать его следующим образом:

```
wrapper<long> wp1;
wrapper<long> wp2{ wp1 };
```

Работает не как ожидалось. Почему - то вызывается дефолтный конструктор копирования вместо моего. 
Добавление:

```
wrapper(const wrapper<T>&) = delete;
```

не спасает положение. Ошибка компиляции, компилятор в упор не видит шаблонного конструктора и просит что - то более подходящее.
Если же убрать квалификатор const, то всё работает:

```
template <class U> wrapper(wrapper<U>&) { SHOW_ME; }
```

методом тыка выявил следующий приоритет перегрузок

```
(wrapper<T>&) > (wrapper<U>&) > (const wrapper<T>&) > default_ctor > (const wrapper<U>&)
```

Пока отказался от const, но на этом проблемы не закончились. Если попытаться применить эту схему для operator= то получаем следующее:

```
template <class U> 
wrapper<T>& operator=(wrapper<U>&) 
{ SHOW_ME return *this; }

...

wrapper<long> wp1;
wrapper<long> wp2;
wp1 = wp2;
```

Опять вызыватся дефолтная версия, хотя const уже нет. Перебирая разные варианты случайно обнаружил что если в класс добавить определение

```
wrapper<T>& operator=(const wrapper<T>&);
```

То всё работает и вызывается вариант с class U но как?! Я же просто добавил определение которое в коде не используется. Я каким - то образом затер дефолтный оператор? Но даже если я добавлю тело в эту функцию, то всё равно компилятор предпочтет шаблонную, а без этого определения видеть её отказывался.

1. Есть какое - то внятное объяснение всей логики работы этих перегрузок или это баги компилятора или я что - то делаю не так?
2. Как эффективнее обезопасить классы от несанкционированного копирования?

Answer (score 1):

У Мейерса в "Эффективный и современный С++" есть очень похожая ситуация (раздел 5.4). Вкратце суть в том, что начинается обычное разрешение перегрузок.

Наличие `= delete` не означает, что конструктор не участвует в разрешении перегрузки, а просто что у него нет тела. Далее, при передаче lvalue `wp1` в конструктор можно передавать его либо сгенерированному конструктору, либо вашему шаблонному. Сгенерированный (вернее, конструктор по умолчанию, он как раз не генерируется - вы запретили) конструктор оказывается более точным соответствием, при том что и для него, и для шаблонного требуется добавление `const` - результат понятен. Но если убрать `const` у шаблонного, то он получается соответствующим в большей мере (не требует добавления `const`) и, соответственно, вызывается именно он.

Это проясняет ситуацию?

Если, например, ввести (и запретить) копирующий по умолчанию без `const`,

```
wrapper(wrapper<T>&) = delete;
```

и при этом передать rvalue - проблемы не возникнет:

```
wrapper<long> wp2{std::move(wp1)};
```